Firefox add-on to allow/block sites
I would like to list some sites (like Gmail, and Wikipedia), and put every other site under password. Is there a free extension for Firefox for this, or even not free? Alternatively, a very simple solution (on Ubuntu) would be welcome (but only if really simple, like putting a script in .rclocal).
Other solutions Firefox plugin to block sites don't quite do what I need.
